# Clicking through slides in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a game with pygame and want to show an introduction. My issue is I want the player to be able to click through each slide until the end, where it would transition to the game itself. Currently I have a loop where it goes through all of the slides immediately. 
Is there a way I can format this so a player could click slide by slide? Thank you!

I've tried various types of looping and iteration. A work around I found was to make a ton of different while statements, e.g. "while intro1" go into "while intro2", but it is very cumbersome. I'm hoping there's a better way.

```
        #introduction screen
        while intro:
            img1 = pygame.image.load("./sprites/img1.png")
            img2 = pygame.image.load("./sprites/img2.png")
            img3 = pygame.image.load("./sprites/img3.png")
            img4 = pygame.image.load("./sprites/img4.png")
            imgs = [img1, img2, img3, img4]
            display_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0))
            display_surface.blit(img1, (0, 0))
            pygame.display.update()
            events = pygame.event.get()
            for event in events:
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                    for i in range(len(imgs)):
                        display_surface.blit(imgs[i], (0, 0))
                        i += 1
                        pygame.display.update()
                        if i >= 3:
                            intro = False
                            run = True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit of reorganizing is in order.  First off, you will keep track of which image you are on using `current_image`.  It is set to 0 before the loop, meaning we'll start at the first image.

The images themselves don't change on each pass through the loop.  They only need to be loaded once BEFORE the loop.

You have too much in your `for event in events:` loop.  In here you should do the bare minimum changes that a certain key press will change.  So on click, we change the `current_image` to increase by 1 and that's it.

After everything, you blit the image to the screen and update. Hopefully this helps.

```
   #introduction screen
    current_image = 0

    img_names = ["./sprites/img1.png", "./sprites/img2.png", "./sprites/img3.png", "./sprites/img4.png"]
    imgs = [pygame.image.load(img) for img in img_names]

    display_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0))
    while intro:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                current_image  +=1
        display_surface.blit(imgs[current_image], (0, 0))
        pygame.display.update()
        if current_image   >= 3:
            intro = False
            run = True
```

Comment: You can move `display_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0))` outside the loop, too.

Comment: `imgs = ["./sprites/img1.png", "./sprites/img2.png", "./sprites/img3.png", "./sprites/img4.png"]` and `imgs = [pygame.image.load(img) for img in imgs]`

Comment: Nice! I've added this just with different names for the images and the image file names in case the names are needed later on.

Comment: Thank you so much! I switched out MOUSEBUTTONUP with MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and it works great. Otherwise it skips every other slide on my computer. **Edit: I made a stupid mistake haha. Besides the up/down thing this works perfectly. Thank you so much!